# How to apply odd and even on a live search table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I created a page which grabs data from a database and outputted the data in a table. I wanted a live search for my table so the script below is what I've found on the internet.

Now the odd and even styling are in CSS. If I search the table the styling is weird because it's applying the styling from the beginning, and not the styling after searching.

The issue: I have multiple tr's with the same color after searching

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#mySearchbar").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr:not(.th)").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
  tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
  }

  tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: `.toggle()` hides or displays the row, it doesn't actually remove the element from the DOM. So as far as CSS is concerned, those rows are still there and count for the odd/even calculation. If you want to include *only* the visible rows, you need a javascript solution. Possibly using jQuery's `:visible` selector, since you're already using jQuery..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @rickdenhaan suggested in his comment you can use :visible selector with jQuery to give different color to even and odd rows that are currently visible.

Try like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#mySearchbar").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr:not(.th)").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
    // re-setting bg color based on visibility 
    $("#myTable tr:not(.th)").filter(":visible").each(function(index) {  
      $(this).css("background-color", ( index%2 ? "#FFFFFF" : "#CCCCCC" ));
    });
  });
});
```

I hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks to both of you! It's now working perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a vanilla-flavored solution with comments.

(Setting the style attribute's `display` property may be slower than setting `line-height`, but avoids needing to account for whitespace-only nodes.)

```js
// Identifiers
const rows = document.querySelectorAll("#myTable TR:not(.th)"),
      searchbar = document.getElementById("mySearchbar");
let searchString;

// Listener
searchbar.addEventListener("keyup", function(){
  
  // Binds `searchString` to the input's current value 
  searchString = event.target.value.trim().toLowerCase();
  
  // Applies the "displayed" CSS class to rows containing the search string
  [...rows].forEach(row => { // The spread operator gives us a proper Array
    if(row.textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) > -1){
      row.classList.add("displayed"); }
    else{
      row.classList.remove("displayed");
    }
  });

  // Applies alternating background colors to the displayed rows
  [...rows].filter(row => row.classList.contains("displayed"))
           .forEach((displayedRow, index) => {
              // Uses the modulo operator (on the index of each row in the filtered array)
              //   to set the condition in the ternary operator to set background color
              displayedRow.style.backgroundColor = 
                index % 2 == 0 ? "#DDDDDD" : "#BBBBBB";
  });
});
```

```css
tr.th {
  background-color: #888888;
  color: #FFFFFF
}
td {
  padding-right: 1ch;
  padding-left: 1ch;
}

tr.displayed{
  /* Use default display style for displayed rows */
  display: ;
}

tr:not(.th):not(.displayed){
  display: none;
}

/* A possibly faster alternative: 
  tr.displayed td {
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1em;
  }
  tr:not(.th):not(.displayed) td {
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
  }
*/
```

```html
<input id="mySearchbar" />
<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="th"><td>Col1</td><td>Col2</td><td>Col3</td></tr>
  <tr class="displayed"><td>The </td><td>quick</td><td>brown</td></tr>
  <tr class="displayed"><td>fox</td><td>jumps</td><td>over</td></tr>
  <tr class="displayed"><td>the</td><td>lazy</td><td>dog.</td></tr>
  <tr class="displayed"><td>The</td><td>quick</td><td>brown</td></tr>
  <tr class="displayed"><td>fox</td><td>jumps</td><td>over</td></tr>
  <tr class="displayed"><td>the</td><td>lazy</td><td>dog.</td></tr>
  <tr class="displayed"><td>The</td><td>quick</td><td>brown</td></tr>
  <tr class="displayed"><td>fox</td><td>jumps</td><td>over</td></tr>
  <tr class="displayed"><td>the</td><td>lazy</td><td>dog.</td></tr>
</table>
```